# How can I read Hexidecimal numbers with the 0x0 extension as either normal Hex numbers or integers

Tags: shell, type-conversion, hex, decimal, i2c

I'm trying to read values in i2c addresses from my raspberry pi. Through the use of i2ctools, I can take an address and store it in a variable.

```
reg_state=$(i2cget -y 1 0x20 0x09)
echo "$reg_state"
:~/ $ 0x0a
```

However, although the address reads in properly, reg_state will keep the hex extension of "0x0" and this hinders doing operations. Say 0x0a was in the register before, and I want to add "1" to that value, the operation won't complete. I think this has to do with the way I'm trying to achieve my goal. Right now my code looks like this:

```
7 addition(){
8   reg_state=$(i2cget -y 1 0x20 0x09)
9   i=$(echo "obase=10; $reg_state"| bc)
10  write=$(i+adj )
}
...
25
26#Main Shell Script
27
28 op=$1
29 adj=$2
30 if [ $1 -gt 0 ]
31 then
32   addition
33 fi
```

What I'm attempting to do is read in the value of the register at an address, convert it to a decimal number and then add it with any number I want. However, I noticed that I am unable to use `echo "obase=10; $reg_state | bc"` because of the presence of '0x'. When converting hex numbers without the extension everything works fine, and they can be added like normal.

That being said, is there anyway I can get rid of the '0x' part and just have what's left so I can do my arithmetic in peace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need `bc` to do integer math, even on hex numbers. Just use shell arithmetic expansion. `echo "$(( 0xA + 1))"` will display 11, for example. And if you need the result in hex:

```
printf "0x%X" $(( 0xA + 1))
```

will print 0xB.